# Unable to use append and reshape functions in the same program in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, reshape

I am writing a code which will take an input from users and convert it into a matrix. I am using `append()` and `reshape()` functions in my code, and to use them I am importing `numpy` and `array` libraries, but on doing so I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
> 2020.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
> pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
> 2020.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
> exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)   File "C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/matrix multliplication",
> line 30, in 
> new_arr = arr.reshape(i,j) AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'reshape'

My code:

```
from numpy import *
from array import *
print("Enter the details of 1st Matrix")
i = int(input("Enter the number of Rows"))
j = int(input("Enter the number of Columns"))
print("NOTE:Number of columns of 1st matrix should be equal to Number  of rows of 2nd matrix")
print("Enter the details of 2st Matrix")
m = int(input("Enter the number of Rows"))
n = int(input("Enter the number of Columns"))

if j == m:
    arr = array('i', [])
    arr1 = array('i', [])

    p = i * j
    q = m * n

    print("Enter the values for 1st matrix")

    for d in range(p):
        x = int(input("Enter the value"))
        arr.append(x)

    print("Enter the values for 2st matrix")

    for e in range(q):
        y = int(input("Enter the value"))
        arr1.append(y)

    new_arr = arr.reshape(i,j)
    new_arr1 = arr1.reshape(m,n)

    print(arr)
    print(arr1)
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use `numpy` and the `array` packages together.  Use one or the other.

Comment: But I need both so can you suggest any method to use both?

Comment: Python `list` has an `append` method.  Use that, and forget the `array` module.  Don't confuse yourself with too many packages.

Comment: In Python, each class of object has its own set of defined `methods`.  A list has `.append`, and `ndarray` has a `.reshape`.  Strings, `dict` also have separate methods.  At each point in your code you should know what the variable is (its `type`) and only use the appropriate `method`.  Keep the documentation at hand.

Comment: I am using append module only you can see that in the above code.Still I am getting error

Comment: I think the main issue is you are mixing up methods from different classes leading to confusion. As @hpaulj suggested, you should look into the documentation of the modules you are using to check which methods are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make an `array.array` (it could just as well be a list, `[]`)

```
arr = array('i', [])   
p = i * j
print("Enter the values for 1st matrix")
for d in range(p):
    x = int(input("Enter the value"))
    arr.append(x)
```

`arr` is still a `array.array`.  Read the `array` docs.  Do you see any `reshape` method?  If not don't do the following:

```
new_arr = arr.reshape(i,j)
```

`array.array` is not multidimensional.  It's just a memory efficient version of a flat list.  In an iterative session like this it doesn't provide any benefit compared to the builtin `list` class.

Here's a simple interactive way of inputing values:

```
In [143]: alist = []
In [144]: for _ in range(4):
     ...:     alist.append(int(input()))     # list append
     ...: 
1
3
5
2
In [145]: alist
Out[145]: [1, 3, 5, 2]
In [146]: arr = np.array(alist)       # make a numpy.ndarray
In [147]: arr
Out[147]: array([1, 3, 5, 2])
In [148]: arr = arr.reshape(2,2)      # this has a reshape method
In [149]: arr
Out[149]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [5, 2]])
```

or taking all values in one line:

```
In [150]: alist = input().split()
1 3 5 2
In [151]: alist
Out[151]: ['1', '3', '5', '2']
In [152]: arr = np.array(alist, dtype=int).reshape(2,2)
In [153]: arr
Out[153]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [5, 2]])
```

Note I used

```
import numpy as np
```

This is standard practice.  It allows us to clearly identify numpy functions, such as with `np.array`.

Your use of

```
from numpy import *
from array import *
```

can create confusion.  Is `array()` a call to the `numpy` function, or the `array` one?  `*` imports are allowed, but usually discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

`reshape` is a function provided by numpy and would work on numpy arrays. To use `reshape`, you will need to convert your `arr` variable to a numpy array.

Comment: Sir how can we convert array into numpy array?Can you please explain or give example in context of the above code.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need both of them? Conversion is simple: `np.array(arr)` would do the conversion.

Comment: I am using array because I want to add values to empty array that I have declared in the start and with numpy I am not able to append values and hence I am using array.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html

Comment: Don't recommend `np.append`!

Comment: Any specific reason?

Comment: `np.append` is a just a cover for `np.concatenate`.  It's not a list clone, and often misused.  People don't read it docs with enough care.